# What is the best strategy for someone stuck in quicksand?

Tags: water-bodies

So in my story a character accidentally got stuck in quicksand. The quicksand area is about as big as a small pond. My character is solo and cant call for help. What should he/she do to get out quickly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122587/discussion-on-question-by-9degreas-what-is-the-best-strategy-for-someone-stuck-i).

Answer (score 7):

**Just Float**

FYI, quicksand is impossible to sink in if you just don't move, so your character should just stay still and float, then slowly (and *carefully*) adjust their position. For more on that, please look at [https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/quicksand-science-why-it-traps-how-to-escape#:~:text=Floating%20in%20Quicksand,about%202%20grams%20per%20milliliter.&text=At%20that%20level%20of%20density,on%20it%E2%80%94until%20they%20move](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/quicksand-science-why-it-traps-how-to-escape#:%7E:text=Floating%20in%20Quicksand,about%202%20grams%20per%20milliliter.&text=At%20that%20level%20of%20density,on%20it%E2%80%94until%20they%20move).